# How to load load example data automatically in mobile app

Tags: javascript, hybrid-mobile-app, indexeddb

I have a hybrid mobile webapp, which presents data to the user.
In online mode, the data is received from the web server via regular http GET requests.
In offline mode, the data is loaded from a .zip file on the mobile device. Loading the data requires human interaction to select the .zip file.

I want to add a small example dataset to the mobile app, that show potential users, that don't have a .zip file yet, how they could view their data.
So, I'm looking for a way to load the data automatically, when in offline mode, as if there was a .zip file and the user selected it.
What would be a good way to do this?
For example, can I embed an IndexedDB file in the mobile app that will be loaded automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Could you just ship the app with a zip file you made put in the place you are putting the user's zipfile when they upload?

Comment: I can. But opening a .zip file requires user interaction (the user has to click on a button, search and select the file).
For simple experience it is better that the demo .zip file will automatically show up.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using .zip file from local asset file, instead of indexedDb.